# Match until first occurrence only

Tags: python, regex, pandas

My pandas dataframe column `center` looks as follows:

```
In [6]: df.center.head()
Out[6]:
0    /Users/sachin/uniwork/IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
1    /Users/sachin/uniwork/IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
2    /Users/sachin/uniwork/IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
3    /Users/sachin/uniwork/IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
4    /Users/sachin/uniwork/IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
Name: center, dtype: object
```

I wish to get rid of all the junk before `IMG`. However, when I do the following string replacement, it replaces *everything* around IMG, before and after the IMG folder.

```
In [7]: df.head().center.str.replace(r'[^IMG]+?','')
Out[7]:
0    IMG
1    IMG
2    IMG
3    IMG
4    IMG
Name: center, dtype: object
```

I assumed that putting `?` would stop it searching beyond the first occurrence of IMG but this was certainly not the case as seen above.

What is the correct way of doing the above regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another method with the help of split though I prefer regex i.e

```
df.center.apply(lambda x : '/IMG'+x.split('IMG')[-1])
```

Output:

```
0    /IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
1    /IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
2    /IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
3    /IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
4    /IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
Name: center, dtype: object
```

Or Thanks @Zero

```
'/IMG' + df.center.str.rsplit('/IMG', 1).str[1]
```

Comment: `'/IMG' + df.center.str.rsplit('/IMG', 1).str[1]` perhaps?

Comment: I use str.split but coundn't access [1] i.e I dint use `str[1]`. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Use `'.*(?=IMG/)'` - matches everything before the last `IMG/` in the string.

```
In [3165]: df.center.str.replace('.*(?=IMG/)', '')
Out[3165]:
0    IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
1    IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
2    IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
3    IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
4    IMG/center_2017_09_17_20...
Name: center, dtype: object
```

`.*` - Match everything 
`(?=IMG/)` - Until you come across pattern `IMG/` capture the group ignoring the pattern i.e `IMG`. Later replace the captured group.

Comment: For future reference could you explain what each thing regex symbol does?

Comment: @Zero is my explanation Ohk? Do edit it if I'm wrong.